# Txredisapi exceptions.RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, redis, twisted, reactor

I am trying to delete all keys except some in Redis, and I do get the following exception:

```
  ... File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 572, in dataReceived
    return self.rawDataReceived(data)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/txredisapi/protocol.py", line 184, in rawDataReceived

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 589, in setLineMode
    return self.dataReceived(extra)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 564, in dataReceived
    why = self.lineReceived(line)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/txredisapi/protocol.py", line 134, in lineReceived

exceptions.RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Here is the code:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def resetAll(self):
    dict=yield self.factory.conn.keys()        
    for xyz in dict:
        if xyz<>"game" and xyz<>"people" and xyz<>"said":
            val = yield self.factory.conn.delete(xyz)

# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from twisted.internet import reactor 
    conn = txredisapi.lazyRedisConnectionPool(reconnect = True)
    factory = STSFactory(conn)
    factory.clients = []

    print "Server started"
    reactor.listenTCP(11000,factory)
    reactor.listenTCP(11001,factory)
    reactor.listenTCP(11002,factory)
    reactor.run()
```

When I call resetAll function with around 725 keys in Redis, I got the exception fired. With lower numbers like 200 etc it is not fired. Anybody has an idea what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Issue a `MONITOR` command in `redis-cli`, then run your program. It may show more hints.

Comment: Monitor command only shows "keys *" , nothing else.

Comment: Then it isn't reaching the delete command. Have you tried https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py ? It simplifies a lot what you are trying to do. In a minute you can code what your current program intends to do in Redis (KEYS/DEL).

Comment: Thanks. I am okay with txredisapi and its way of handling redis. Looks like this is a bug and needs to be fixed. https://github.com/fiorix/txredisapi/issues/10

Comment: ...It is opened since Jan'11 ? Redis-py last commit was on last 13th, while txredisapi's was on Feb'11. No good.

Comment: How can I use it? As you can see from my code I use connection pool of txredisapi inside Protocol of STSFactory. Unfortunately I do not know how to do that with redis-py. If you want I can open a new question for this.

Comment: Are you running linux and if so do you have root access ?

Comment: Mac OS X Server 10.6.8 , and I have root access.

Comment: It was a bug in the code, which I fixed after someone opened a ticket. There's a blog post on it: http://musta.sh/2012-08-08/a-victim-of-recursion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on a terminal of a Linux/Mac computer with root access, and Python and Git installed:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py.git redis-py
cd redis-py
sudo python setup.py install
```

> Behind the scenes, redis-py uses a connection pool to manage
>   connections to a Redis server. By default, each Redis instance you
>   create will in turn create its own connection pool. You can override
>   this behavior and use an existing connection pool by passing an
>   already created connection pool instance to the connection_pool
>   argument of the Redis class.

#### Example (save it as delkeys.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import redis

pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
keys = r.keys()
for key in keys:
    if key<>"game" and key<>"people" and key<>"said":
        r.del(key)
```

Take this with the reminder that I haven't tested, but your comments may shape the final solution or you can go from here. Always monitor in redis-cli to be sure.

Comment: txredisapi: An asynchronous Python client for the Redis database, based on Twisted. txredis: An asynchronous Redis client library for the Twisted Python framework . Both say that they are async, what about redis-py? By the way thanks for your support.

Comment: @antirez would say: "Mature and supported. Currently the way to go for Python." (by http://redis.io/clients). You're welcome dude! =D